# Haskell: Confused about type of `>>=` operator

Tags: haskell, bind, monads, io-monad

I'm working my way through some introductory Haskell materials and am currently going through Monads.  I conceptually understand that the `>>=` operator is of type:

`(Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

In that context, I'm confused as to why the following code works, i.e., why it doesn't result in a type mismatch:

```
main = getLine >>= \xs -> putStrLn xs
```

Since we know that `getLine :: IO String`, I'd assume that it can be 'bound' with a function of type `String -> IO String`.  However `putStrLn` is of a different type: `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`.

So why does Haskell allow us to use `>>=` with these two functions?

Comment: `a` is a `String`, `m` is `IO` and `b` is `()` (the unit, or empty tuple). Thus, the type of the lambda is `String -> IO ()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's just line up the types:

```
(>>=)    ::  m      a -> (     a ->  m  b) -> m b
getLine  :: IO String
putStrLn ::              (String -> IO ())
```

Here we have `m = IO`, `a = String`, and `b = ()`, so we can substitute these into `>>=`'s type signature to get a final type signature of

```
(>>=) :: IO String -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

Answer (score 5):

`()` is a valid type (called unit, note that it contains only one possible non-bottom value) and in the definition would be `b`.

`a` = `String` and `b` = `()` thus we get:

`IO String -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()`

Comment: (It contains two values, the other being bottom. ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Since we know that `getLine :: IO String`, I'd assume that it can be 'bound' with a function of type `String -> IO String`.

Why would you think that? Look again at the type signature:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Thing in the left is `m a`, thing on the right is `m b`. Most particularly the bit in the middle, `a -> m b`, says that the function you pass to `>>=` takes an `a` and returns an `m b`. It doesn't say it has to return `m a`, it says it can be `m b`, where `b` is any random type. It doesn't have to match `a`.

In your example, the lambda function takes a `String` and returns an `IO ()`. So `a = String` and `b = ()`. And that's fine.